# Injection of configuration when creating an instance from a JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a code snippet that creates an instance based on the configuration specified in the JSON file (I am thinking about `LoginLogic`)

```
public ILoginModule GetLoginModule()
{
    if (loginModule == null)
    {
        loginModule = new LoginModule.LoginModule(_configuration);

        Type loginLogicType = CreateTypeFromConfiguration("LoginModule", "LoginLogic", "MyProject.Modules.LoginModule.Logic.LoginLogic");
        loginModule.SetLoginLogic((ILoginLogic)Activator.CreateInstance(loginLogicType));
    }
    return loginModule;
}
```

Here's what the `LoginLogic` class looks like

```
public class LoginLogic : ILoginLogic
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    protected ILoginRepository loginRepository;

    public LoginLogic()
    {
    }

    public LoginLogic(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        loginRepository = new LoginRepository(_configuration);
    }
}
```

`Activator` uses an empty constructor to create an object

I need to have the data that I call in the next constructor

`loginRepository` I can move because it does not change anything

What to do with `configuration`? It is injected automatically by Net. Core

Comment: We obviously can't see a lot of your custom code here, but it looks like you're just reinventing the wheel of `Configure<TOptions>`. Why not use what's already built in?

Answer (score 4):

There is a little known static class in NetCore which allows you to the CreateInstance but with injection..

From the top of my head, I think its in the *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions* namespace and its called `ActivatorUtilities`.

You call it like so:

```
var instance = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(ServiceProvider, typeof(typeToInstantiate));
```

It requires a `IServiceProvider` instance which contains all the objects it can inject for.

Is that what you're looking for?